# IBDCursor IntelXDK stop

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am implementing a Call list Where LOAD need a flame already Made is need list and Place checkbox Mark que um not been present . However NOT Giving .

I use a cursor idea , EO Bank Used And IndexedDB data , I do a Search All Students " , " the code " student " to equal When the " student " code in Table Presence , the problem happens here! HE DOES NOT When paragraph are a Correct ANSWER , he continues to test everyone.

The code below :

```
db.transaction ("tbl_PESSOAS"). ObjectStore ("tbl_PESSOAS"). get (cursor.value.COD_IDENT_PESSO) .onsuccess = function (event) {


$ wrapper = document.querySelector ('# check_presenca');

   HTMLTemporario = $ wrapper.innerHTML;
   = event.target.result person;

   if (pessoa.FLG_IDENT_PESSO == "A" && cursor.value.FLG_IDENT_PESSO == "M") {
      var w_codigo_reuniao = sessionStorage.getItem ("w_codigo_reuniao");
      w_aux var = 01;
      var bd = db.transaction ("tbl_PRESENCA"). ObjectStore ("tbl_PRESENCA")
     index = bd.index ("COD_IDENT_REUNI");
        index.openCursor (w_codigo_reuniao) .onsuccess = function (event) {
        var = vector event.target.result;
        if (vector) {

        if (pessoa.COD_IDENT_PESSO == vetor.value.COD_IDENT_PESSO) {

         HTMLNovo = '<li class = "item-item checkbox uib_w_69 widget" data-UIB = "ionic / checkbox" data-view = "0"> <label class = "checkbox"> <input class = "check" type = " checkbox "name =" '+ pessoa.COD_IDENT_PESSO +' "checked> <input id =" codigoPessoaPresente "value =" '+ pessoa.COD_IDENT_PESSO +' "type =" hidden "> </ label> '+ pessoa.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO +' </ li> ';

         HTMLNovo = HTMLNovo + HTMLTemporario;

         $ wrapper.innerHTML = HTMLNovo;
       } else {
       HTMLNovo = '<li class = "item-item checkbox uib_w_69 widget" data-UIB = "ionic / checkbox" data-view = "0"> <label class = "checkbox"> <input class = "check" type = " checkbox "name =" '+ pessoa.COD_IDENT_PESSO +' "> <input id =" codigoPessoaPresente "value =" '+ pessoa.COD_IDENT_PESSO +' "type =" hidden "> </ label> '+ pessoa.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO +' </ li > ';

       HTMLNovo = HTMLNovo + HTMLTemporario;

       $ wrapper.innerHTML = HTMLNovo;

       vetor.continue ();
       }
     }
   };
  }
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to provide a key range if you want to filter the data.

```
store.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.lowerBound(0))
```

You can find some more info over [here](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2012/01/indexed-db-reading-multiple-records.html) and about the different IDBKeyRanges [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dfn-key-range)